# Start tmux with -2

Tags: configuration, tmux

I am using `tmux`. I am starting it via `tmux -2` the `-2` enables 256 color support. Instead of starting it with `-2` I would like to change my `.tmux.conf` file to do that for me.

What do I have to put in my `.tmux.conf` file that is equivalent to `tmux -2`? The [**Arch Documentation**](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Tmux) suggest:

`set -g default-terminal "screen-256color"`

This however doesn't seem to have any effect whatsoever.

Answer (score 1):

I think the tmux.conf file shouldn’t literally read: set -g default-terminal "screen-256color"  but something like:

set -g xterm "screen-256color"

you can check your $TERM variable to see what your system has as the default shell.

```
echo $TERM
```

then put that in the place of "default-terminal" you may be able to use the $TERM variable in the conf file, but I'm not certain about that.

if that still doesnt work, you could write an alaias for tmux, as:

```
alias tmux='tmux -2'
```